# Cannot Display Multiple Entities of a xml File while I can display one

Tags: javascript, xml

This is the function I use

```
            function displayXML(string) {
                var i;
                var xmlDoc = $.parseXML(string);
                var xml = $(xmlDoc);
                var table = "<tr><th>Author</th><th>Title</th><th>Genre</th><th>Price</th><th>Publish Date</th><th>Description</th></tr>";
                var x = xml.find('book').size();
                for ( i = 0; i < x; i++) {
                    table += "<tr><td>" +
                    xml[i].getElementsByTagName('author')[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue +
                    "</td><td>" +
                    xml[i].getElementsByTagName('title')[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue +
                    "</td><td>" +
                    xml[i].getElementsByTagName('genre')[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue +
                    "</td><td>" +
                    xml[i].getElementsByTagName('price')[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue +
                    "</td><td>" +
                    xml[i].getElementsByTagName('publish_date')[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue +
                    "</td><td>" +
                    xml[i].getElementsByTagName('description')[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue +
                    "</td></tr>";
                }
                document.getElementById("showResults").innerHTML = table;

            }
```

Thing is , I can successfully display this string coming from php

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><catalog>  <book id="1">    <author>KAPIOS</author>    <title>KATI0</title>    <genre>KATI GENRE</genre>    <price>50</price>    <publish_date>2000-01-05</publish_date>    <description>AXAM</description>  </book></catalog>
```

but I cant do the same for lines that contain 2 or more books

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><catalog>  <book id="9">    <author>Ralls, Kim</author>    <title>Midnight Rain</title>    <genre>Fantasy</genre>    <price>5.95</price>    <publish_date>2000-12-16</publish_date>    <description>A former architect battles corporate zombies,       an evil sorceress, and her own childhood to become queen       of the world.</description>  </book>  <book id="10">    <author>Corets, Eva</author>    <title>Maeve Ascendant</title>    <genre>Fantasy</genre>    <price>5.95</price>    <publish_date>2000-11-17</publish_date>    <description>After the collapse of a nanotechnology       society in England, the young survivors lay the       foundation for a new society.</description>  </book></catalog>
```

Also here is the error message

```
 "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getElementsByTagName' of undefineddisplayXML"
```

It just seems strange to me than using getElementsByTag is possible on one case but unusable in another.

Function used to "extract" (I'm generating it via a php call) the xml,this one is working

```
        function getBook() {
                clearResults();
                var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
                var url = "resources/getBooksByTitle.php";
                var dataToSent = "dataToSent=" + document.getElementById("booksDropDown").value;
                request.open("POST", url, true);
                request.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
                request.onreadystatechange = function() {
                    if (request.readyState == 4 && request.status == 200) {
                        var return_data = request.responseText;
                        displayXML(return_data);

                    }
                }
                request.send(dataToSent);
                document.getElementById("showResults").innerHTML = "processing...";
            }
```

Second function which doesn't work

```
function searchBook() {
                clearResults();
                var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
                var url = "resources/getBooksByKeyword.php";
                var dataToSent = "dataToSent=" + document.getElementById("searchBox").value;
                request.open("POST", url, true);
                request.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
                request.onreadystatechange = function() {
                    if (request.readyState == 4 && request.status == 200) {
                        var return_data = request.responseText;
                        displayXML(return_data);
                    }
                }
                request.send(dataToSent);
                document.getElementById("showResults").innerHTML = "processing...";

            }
```

Comment: Show us how you extract the XML

Comment: @SuperCoolHandsomeGelBoy Editted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function displayXML(string) {
            var i;
            var xmlDoc = $.parseXML(string);
            var xml = $(xmlDoc);
            var table = "<tr><th>Author</th><th>Title</th><th>Genre</th><th>Price</th><th>Publish Date</th><th>Description</th></tr>";
            var x = xml.find('book').length;
            for ( i = 0; i < x; i++) {
                table += "<tr><td>" +
                xml.find('book')[i].getElementsByTagName('author')[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue +
                "</td><td>" +
                xml.find('book')[i].getElementsByTagName('title')[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue +
                "</td><td>" +
                xml.find('book')[i].getElementsByTagName('genre')[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue +
                "</td><td>" +
                xml.find('book')[i].getElementsByTagName('price')[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue +
                "</td><td>" +
                xml.find('book')[i].getElementsByTagName('publish_date')[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue +
                "</td><td>" +
                xml.find('book')[i].getElementsByTagName('description')[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue +
                "</td></tr>";
            }
            document.getElementById("showResults").innerHTML = table;

        }
```

The `xml` object itself is not an array, so you extract data from 1 book only(size of a non-array is always 1). Use this one instead.